# Hazelcast member authentication ignores group password

Tags: hazelcast

I am using hazelcast 3.11.2, free version. Trying to enforce authentication, i.e. group password, but it is not working. Hazelcast is ignoring it, and letting nodes join the cluster anyway, without specifying or specifying a wrong password.

According to hazelcast resources on the net, newer versions starting with 3.8.2 will let members join the cluster with the same group name even if the group password is different / not specified. On the other hand JAAS is supported with Enterprise version only.

So, how should authentication be added in the hazelcast's community edition? Try and hack in something when the members are joining or there is a better, standardized way?

Open to recommendations... Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Group password was removed because it wasn't meant to be used as security.  For community edition, you can try setting **hazelcast.application.validation.token** at runtime for all your members.

Answer (score 0):

Security is an enterprise feature and can not be accessed in community version.

Comment: Yeah, I understand it is, as I had mentioned. I was wondering if there are any approaches to this for the community edition... or it's really, nope, can't do anything?

So far I am down to network isolation of namespaces.. which should prevent pollution and provide some security to it.